# App error с деплоем на heroku

Tags: python, github, flask, heroku

Модель ML отсюда:
[Ошибка с возвратом результата](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1320865/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0)

Она же:
https://github.com/EugeneWenew/MLnodel_flask.py

Билд на хероке вроде успешен, однако имею:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама модель рабочая. Про проверке на 127.0.0.1:5000 показывает результат.

Логи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, проверьте, что ваш web-dyno запущен. Вы можете сделать это через панель управления приложением на вашем дэшборде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]